# Shopify dynamic metafields for product when it's a 404 (Liquid nested in Liquid?) without Shopify API

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

Whenever a URL results in a 404, I have a javascript that fires that redirects conditionally to a relevant URL.

This has worked great for some time.

But now I want to be able to redirect specific products that have been Drafted... to specific redirect URLs using metafields... and without utilizing Shopify API.

WHAT I HAVE DONE :
I have successfully allowed administrators to enter a URL in a metafield (`redirect_url`).

And I have been able to output that to the product page :
`{{ product.metafields.custom.redirect_url.value }}`

And I have been able to pass that to javascript :
`const redirect_url = "{{ product.metafields.custom.redirect_url.value }}"; console.log(redirect_url); // output : the correct redirect URL`

BUT... the metafields are NOT available when the product is Drafted and results in a 404...

BUT I have discovered you can access metafields even when not on that product page... like this :
`{{ product['example-product-handle'].metafields.custom.redirect_url.value }}`

but I need something dynamic...

`{{handle}}` is available and valid... and this would be golden :
`const redirect_url = "{{ product['{{ handle }}'].metafields.custom.redirect_url.value }}";`

but that breaks and the result is a mangled string :(

so i'm up against the wall with this and seeking help... I would really appreciate any solutions anyone has to offer!

To reiterate the goal :
I need to be able to access the metafields of a product even when it's a 404. Normally, Shopify provides access to the metafileds easily, but NOT when it's a 404.

So I want to be able to take the available data `{{ handle }}` and use it to access the metafields

I also want to avoid using Shopify Redirects because I want to make it easier and convenient for content administrators by being able to change the redirect URL themselves inline on the Edit Product screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered through experimentation that using routine Shopify Redirects can manage this (Online Store -> Navigation -> View Redirects).

If you make a redirect for a product... and it is Status -> Active... the redirect will NOT fire.

But... if it is Status -> Draft... the redirect WILL fire.

In other words... Shopify Redirects will only fire if the request results in a 404.

Therefore, you can manage temporary public products simply by toggling the Status.

My "Use Case Scenario" : A Livestream Promo that is live for a 1-hour window 2-3 times per week. This allows a non-code-savvy admin to easily manage the livestream status... therefore it is "good enough".

In the future... I will use metafields to allow an admin to enter a livestream schedule and a redirect URL... and the product will simply remain Status -> Active (therefore allowing access to all the usual metafields). Then Javascript will handle the redirection based on the schedule.